# Has the mystery of God stuck at the center of the galaxy ever been resolved?

Tags: star-trek, movie

In *Star Trek V: The Final Frontier*, the Enterprise reached the self-proclaimed God who *seemed* to be stuck at the center of galaxy. He even needed a starship to escape.

Spock even asked why he needed starship if he was God, but "God" dodged the question.

Has this mystery ever been resolved in the canon (novels etc)?  Do we ever learn the true identity of that being?

Comment: I think most Star Trek fans wanted to just forget about that movie... I know i did.

Comment: There was no _Star Trek V_. They skipped directly from IV to VI for reasons which remain mysterious to this day. Anyone who tells you otherwise is high.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No. In [the movie novelization](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_V%3a_The_Final_Frontier_%28novel%29), it was revealed that this being had been imprisoned there, leaving the crew wondering, "what being was so powerful that it could have imprisoned this one!"

That answer was never revealed. All that was revealed was that the being wasn't "God", just a being that was able to touch Sybok's mind. It claimed to be God, because that's what would motivate Sybok to seek it out, giving it a chance to escape.

However, in [non-canon books](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/God_%28Sha_Ka_Ree%29)...

> According to the non-canon Q Continuum series of novels by Greg Cox,
>   the Sha Ka Ree entity was known as "The One," and was exiled to the
>   center of the galaxy for causing a civil war centered around the
>   premature destruction of the legendary Tkon Empire millennia before
>   being rediscovered by Sybok and the crew of the Enterprise-A. He was
>   an associate and contemporary of 0 (pronounced "Nil", as in nothing),
>   the Beta XII-A entity, or (*) as 0 referred to it (used in type
>   because its real name was apparently unpronounceable, or even
>   incomprehensible, by Humans), and Gorgan in this endeavor.

Comment: Book's name please.

Comment: BTW, it wasn't just Sybok, but it was a rumor spread across galaxy saying the location of God.

Comment: Book same name as the movie. I added a link to it.  It was the book adaptation of the movie, and contained several details not in the film.